# Identify a TV series involving characters in spaceships

Tags: story-identification, tv, spaceship

It was a series which I watched in 2005-8. It was about a crew in a cargo ship who have various adventures throughout the Galaxy. I remember the protagonist was a man, the engineer had special arms that could change into tools and there was also a woman. It's a 3D animated type.

Comment: ... so the arms could change into a woman? :P

Comment: @SeanDuggan beat me to it :D

Comment: Does this look familiar? It matches the dates: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tripping_the_Rift